# Cannot read product images on list page in Magento2

Tags: gallery, product, magento2

I'm trying to load product images on list page. Here is my code:

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){

     $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

The **$_product** variable is fine. The variable **$images** is always null.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this with following code:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){

    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);        
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the `addMediaGalleryData` method.

See [this answer on magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/228181/9951) for more details.